# Clone implementation not passing 'equals' test, all variables/fields are the same when debugging

Tags: java, clone, equals

I'm doing a homework assignment to pass a series of tests, I implemented my own equals and clone function, and can't figure out why the cloned object isn't equal to the original.

I've tried casting the Object to Student in the boolean expression of the if statement, but that hasn't done anything.

Testfile

```java
Name n1 = new Name("John","Rockefeller");
Student s1 = new Student(n1, "123456");
Student s3 = s1.clone();
if ( s1.equals ( s3 ) )
        System.out.println ( "\t\tSuccess - Students s1 and s3 are the same." );
```

class Student implements Cloneable

```java
private Name fullName;
private String id;

@Override
    public Student clone(){
        try {
            Student clone = (Student) super.clone();

            clone.fullName = (Name) fullName.clone();
            return clone;
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }

public boolean equals ( Object obj ) {
        if (this == (Student) obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Student calc = (Student) obj;

        return Objects.equals(this.fullName, calc.fullName) && Objects.equals(this.id, calc.id);
    }
```

Expected:  The test passes, however after watching the variables in the debugging tracker I have no idea why it's not passing.  The values are equal.

Comment: Did you also create an `equals` implementation for the `Name` class?

Comment: Ahh, I did create an equals implementation but I was comparing one of the wrong fields (this.firstName == obj.lastName).  Thanks!

Comment: `if (this == (Student) obj) {` Don't do this. You'll get a `ClassCastException` if `obj` isn't a `Student`, and you don't want that. `if (this == obj) {` is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `clone` method does not copy `id`.  Your `equals` method expects the `id`s to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
Student clone = (Student) super.clone();
clone.fullName = (Name) fullName.clone();
```

But your class says:

```
private Name fullName;
private String id;
```

You are omitting the `id` field. So you should either **add** copying that `id` field, or if it is intended to not be relevant, drop it from your `equals()` implementation!